# different color in one TextView of ListView in Android 4.1

Tags: android, listview

I have two TextViews in a ListView ,bind data by SimpleAdapter,I want to show different color in a single TextView,I use Html.fromHtml,but style can't work,so pls help..

```
simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(NewsListActivity.this, list, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "source" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTitle, R.id.tvSource });
listview.setAdapter(simpleAdapter); 

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list= new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("title", Html.fromHtml("<u>it's an another day.</u>"));
map.put("source", Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffcc00>bbc news</font>"));
list.add(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement a custom ListViewAdapter. In getView(), you can then instantiate your own row layout and set the text color.

Information on custom Adapters can be found e.g. here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

As @FD suggested you need a custom ListView containing a TextView, then in that Text View you can have a sentence with different colors using the code below.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>First line</font><br/><font color='blue'>Second line</font>"));
```